# how to convert query related to calculate work hours in MySQL to MS Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access, php

I want to calculate work hours in each day using MS Access.I have query for same thing in MySQL but this thing is not working in MS Access using pdo php.

query in MySql

```
    SELECT MachineNo, Empcardno, Date, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(tsecs)) AS total_time
FROM (
  SELECT CASE WHEN MachineNo = @mn AND Empcardno = @en AND `Date` = @dt
              THEN @rn := @rn + 1
              ELSE @rn := 1
         END AS rn,
         @mn := MachineNo AS MachineNo, @en := Empcardno AS Empcardno, 
         @dt := `Date` AS `Date`,
         CASE WHEN @rn % 2 = 1 THEN -TIME_TO_SEC(`Time`)
              ELSE TIME_TO_SEC(`Time`)
         END AS tsecs
  FROM timesheet
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @mn := 0, @en := 0, @dt := '', @rn := 0) init
  ORDER BY Date, Time
) t
GROUP BY MachineNo, Empcardno, Date
```

how to convert this query to make compatible with ms access pdo connection using php

table structure and data in ms-access

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaCPp.png

Comment: This query cannot be adopted to MS Access. Build the query for it from the beginning.

Comment: I am familiar with MySQL but i don't  have much knowledge about ms access can you help me to build query for ms access

Comment: *I am familiar with MySQL but i don't have much knowledge about ms access* Perform the same task in MySQL without user-defined variables - all another constructions have direct equivalent in MS Access (subqueries) or may be easily adopted (functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT MachineNo, Empcardno, [Date], 
       FORMAT(SUM(IIF(rn MOD 2 = 0, -TimeValue([Time]), TimeValue([Time]))),'hh:nn:ss') AS total_time
FROM (
  SELECT t1.MachineNo, t1.Empcardno, t1.Date, t1.Time, COUNT(t2.MachineNo) AS rn
  FROM timesheet t1
  LEFT JOIN timesheet t2 ON t2.MachineNo = t1.MachineNo 
                        AND t2.Empcardno = t1.Empcardno
                        AND t2.Date = t1.Date
                        AND TimeValue(t2.Time) < TimeValue(t1.Time)
  GROUP BY t1.MachineNo, t1.Empcardno, t1.Date, t1.Time
)  AS t
GROUP BY MachineNo, Empcardno, Date
```

for complete detail please see the link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62297919/how-to-convert-query-related-to-calculate-work-hours-in-mysql-to-ms-access/62317847#comment110225804_62317847